# how to I change permissions to all subdirectories except for 1 folder using a single find command?

Tags: files, find

I need to change the folder and file permissions in all subfolders except for 1 folder. Currently, I'm running several find/exec commands to make it work.

```
e.g. find /mystuff/temp/videos -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

The folder structure would be something like (with the necessary permissions I need):

```
mystuff
    -> folder1 (ignored)
        -> subfolder1 (permissions changed)
    -> folder2 (permissions changed)
    -> folder3 (permissions changed)
```

Is it possible? If yes, with what  `find`  etc. command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
find /mystuff/temp/videos -type d ! -name 'folder1' -exec chmod 777 {} +
```

A note that you should not set 777 permission, it's a big hole in security.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `-wholename` test with a not (`!`) to remove the directory.  For example:

```
find /mystuff/temp/videos ! -wholename 'mystuff/folder' -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

From the man page:

> ```
>    -wholename pattern
>       File name matches shell pattern pattern.  The metacharacters  do
>       not treat '/' or '.' specially; so, for example,
>         find . -wholename './sr*sc'
>       will  print an entry for a directory called './src/misc' (if one
>       exists).
> ```

The pattern needs to be in quotes if you use wildcards (`*`) to protect it from the shell.